# Convert UTC string date to valid mongo date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this `TimeStamp = "2017-08-02T08:00:38.977"` which is provided to me from 3rd party API feed. It is already in UTC.

I need to log this into mongo and I want it to be a valid Date type in mongo for querying but I'm struggling to convert the damn thing correctly so it's stored 'as is'.

e.g.

`TimeStamp = new Date(TimeStamp)` gives me `Wed Aug 02 2017 08:00:38 GMT+0800` which when I insert to mongo appears as `2017-08-02 00:00:38.280Z` i.e. `"TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-08-02T00:00:38.280Z")`

I tried toISOString and various other things but they all change the time in bizarre ways and appear in mongo completely different to what i expect.

Can someone please tell me how to just insert the string variable `2017-08-02T07:55:47.977` into mongo so it remains exactly the same but is Date type.

Regards
fLo

**Update**

Incoming string timestamp from API = 2017-08-02T08:30:41.39

new Date(TimeStamp) = 2017-08-02T00:30:41.390Z

Document in Mongo after insert = "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-08-02T00:30:41.390Z")

Comment: Show the actual document as viewed from the mongo shell. If you are actually using `new Date()` then it should be storing correctly. It's just that the default output format of JavaScript is to use the "local string format". But it still should be actually stored as the correct type, unless you did something different to what you clain

Comment: i added the output i get.. the `new Date` doesn't keep the date the same. As the provided string is already in UTC i should remain the same not rollback 8 hours.

Comment: It's stored correctly, as indicated by the `ISODate` notation in the shell. Why would it "rollback 8 hours"? It was already in UTC when you got it, so there is no need to adjust for a timezone.

Comment: Oh Sorry. Because your API does not have a trailing `Z`. That's all you need add to make it a valid UTC representation for the `Date` constructor. As long as it's **meant** to be UTC that is. If it's actually coming from another timezone then that's another story.

Comment: sigh. yes you are correct. append 'Z' to timeStamp and it's OK now. Can you answer and i'll accept. Thanks ( again )